# Most efficient way for static images on GAE?

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine

I have a Java GAE app that has quite a lot of static graphics, GUI and other elements, about 100 images now, later it will be few hundred. It's all static, no manipulations and no changes and no option to upload new images by users. So just html images [including those referenced by Wicket]. I am wondering what is the most efficient (both from user's perspective and costs). What are you using? I think there are 3 options:
 - store it just with the app
 - datastore and shared cache (it will be up to 100mb of images)
 - 3rd party site

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient way will be to store it on Google App Engine as static files, its convenient because the app update is a simple process and out of the box and you will get the benefits of caching by the front end edge caching and by the browser cache. 
I don't know if this is the cheapest solution, but you should consider using Google Cloud Store or Amazon S3 only/when bandwidth will start to be an issue.

Comment: This will also be cheaper than datastore. Third party youll have to benchmark.